# Access a blender file externally (from a python script)

Tags: python, path

I have a folder named "3D" with all my blender projects from the past year and I wanted to rename this folder to "3D_old" but if I do this, all the textures from my projects stop working because all my paths are absolute.

to fix this issue, i can use the "file>external data>make all paths relatives" option but i would have to do it for approx. 150 .blend files. So I would like to know if it's possible to use python to open the blend files and change the paths automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only with Phyton isn't it possible I think, but with the BatchBlendChanger  Add-on it is.
You can download the Add-on here:
[https://github.com/RivinHD/BatchBlendChanger](https://github.com/RivinHD/BatchBlendChanger/blob/master/BatchBlendChanger.zip)

**Explanation:**

1. Start Blender and install the Add-on.
2. Activate the Add-on.
3. Search in the Search Menu (Shortcut: F3) for "Batch Import".
4. Now you should see a file selector.
5. Select all .blend files you want to change the path to relative.
6. Search in the Search Menu "Batch Start".
7. A Dialog box/Popup should appear with all you selected .blend files.
8. Press OK to start the process.

The process is running and could take a while with 150 files.
If Blender crashes, no problem, restart Blender again. The Process will run again at exactly the same position it was running before the crash.
You should you use the console to start blender. It's easier to restart with the console and you can watch the process.

**Start Blender with the console:**

1. open the console (cmd)
2. Navigate to the installation path of Blender
3. Start blender with the command "blender.exe -d"